# MySQL datetime show 0000 with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, pdo

I'm having troubles trying to insert a timestamp into MySQL always shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00

The scheme for the table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Rawdata` (
`Exchanger` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`Last` float NOT NULL,
`Bid` float NOT NULL,
`Ask` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Exchanger`,`Timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And the code of the php :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Rawdata (Exchanger,Timestamp,Last,Bid,Ask) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    $result = $link->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(1,$exchanger,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(2,$timestamp,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(3,$last,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(4,$bid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(5,$ask,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
```

Also this is the var_dump() of the variables

```
array(5) { [1]=> string(6) "Mt.Gox" [2]=> string(10) "1391036493" 
[3]=> string(6) "929.00" [4]=> string(6) "929.00" [5]=> string(6) "932.90" }
```

I don't know why is not working.. Because in other function i update other table with the same timestamp column and it works :/

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

The `$timestamp` variable comes from this:

```
$apivariable = string(16) "1391038069839089"
```

then i use the following:

```
$timestamp = time($apivariable)
```

Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/vBn0TBvG

Comment: As per your edit: You'll need an extra added function to convert it to a proper date format.

Comment: Have you tried Barmar's suggestion in using `$result->bindValue(2,date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp),PDO::PARAM_STR);`? And Scuzzy has updated his answer being `INSERT INTO Rawdata (Exchanger,Timestamp,Last,Bid,Ask) VALUES(?,FROM_UNIXTIME(?),?,?,?)`

Comment: Also, your questions shows `$query = "INSERT INTO Rawdata (Exchanger,Timestamp,Last,Bid,Ask) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";` but your pastebin file shows `$query = "INSERT INTO Rawdata (Exchanger,Timestamp,Last,Bid,Ask) VALUES(?,NOW(),?,?,?)";`

Comment: The one from Barmar's works perfectly. The other doesn't. About the pastbin it's because i copy the last code i try.

Comment: Ok, well that's good news then. Either `oleksii.svarychevskyi` updates the answer to reflect the change, or for Barmar to put in an answer himself in order to close the question. Or I can put one in ;-)

Comment: That's correct @Fred-ii- . Now i wonder myself, Why it works this way with an INSERT and with and UPDATE i don't need to use the function date().. Only with the time function and the update the row works like a charm.. :/

Comment: Do that. So for future generations someone can solve this problem :P

Comment: Ok, it's posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
$result->bindParam(2,$timestamp,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Use:

```
$result->bindValue(2,date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp),PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

But your column in database has not type timestamp

`Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL

To insert datetime value should be in "0000-00-00 00:00:00" format.

Try `$result->bindValue(2,date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp),PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: You need to use `bindValue`. `bindParam` requires a reference argument.

Comment: The $timestamp variable comes from this:

$apivariable -- string(16) "1391037834716412"

then $timestamp = time($apivariable);

Comment: You should consider showing a bit more code then, meaning all of your variables in your question. Not seeing/knowing what they are, leaves people guessing till the "cows come home". @LuTacmar - Plus, using the built-in `NOW()` function works like a charm.

Comment: See my new comments under your question. @LuTacmar

Answer (score 0):

`$timestamp` a unix timestamp, you need to format/convert it to the appropriate mysql type.

```
INSERT INTO Rawdata (Exchanger,Timestamp,Last,Bid,Ask) VALUES(?,FROM_UNIXTIME(?),?,?,?)
```

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME` should be in the `VALUES` clause, not the list of column names.